# Query object has foreign collections with conditions

Tags: ormlite, foreign-collection

I'm learning to use your ORMLite framework for Android.

But I faced a problem that I tried many ways to resolve but failed.

For example.
I have 2 database classes:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Subject")
public class Subject {
        @DatabaseField(columnName = "id", id = true)
        protected String id;

        @DatabaseField(columnName = "deleteFlag", canBeNull = false, defaultValue = "0")
        protected boolean deleteFlag = false;

        @DatabaseField(columnName = "name", canBeNull = false)
        private String name;

        @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, maxEagerLevel = 3)
        private Collection<Student> students;
        ...
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Student")
public class Student {
        @DatabaseField(columnName = "id", id = true)
        protected String id;

        @DatabaseField(columnName = "deleteFlag", canBeNull = false, defaultValue = "0")
        protected boolean deleteFlag = false;

        @DatabaseField(columnName = "firstName", canBeNull = false)
        private String firstName;

        @DatabaseField(columnName = "lastName", canBeNull = true)
        private String lastName;

        @DatabaseField(columnName = "subjectId", canBeNull = false, foreign = true, foreignColumnName = "id")
        private Subject subject;

        ...
}
```

It requires that the record is not deleted in database, it just be marked by deleteFlag column.

Now, I try to query the all subjects which have "deleteFlag = false". Each subject has list of students which have "deleteFlag = false" too.

Is there a way to query using SubjectDao???

Or I have to do 2 steps:

1. Using SubjectDao to query all the subjects which have "deleteFlag = false";
2. Loop in list of subjects, using StudentDao to query all students of that subject which have "deleteFlag = false". Then set list of students to the subject object.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what are you actually trying to accomplish here.  In the future be careful about giving answers before describing the problem in detail.

Your comments to my previous answer (below) indicate that you wish that the `Collection<Student> students` would only show the students that do not have the `delete` field set to `false`.  Right now [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) does not support custom queries for foreign collections.  Your code will have to ignore the deleted students.

One alternative would be to move the students to a `DeletedStudents` table instead of setting a boolean.

---

If you are trying to just remove all `Subject`s that have the delete flag on and then all of the `Student`s will the delete flag then you can do that with the [`DeleteBuilder`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/DeleteBuilder.html).  You don't have to worry about updating the `Subject`'s collections of students.  When you re-query for a `Subject` it will reflect the changes.

If, instead you want to do something more complex like delete all of the `Subjects` that have no students then you are going to need to use the [`QueryBuilder.join(...)` method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#join%28com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29) with your `DeleteBuilder`.

Comment: I didn't face with the problem in deleting. I just turned the deleteFlag of the record to true then that record is considered DELETED.

Comment: My problem is querying data. For example, I have Subject1 which has 3 Students St1, St2, St3. St1 and St2 have deleteFlag off, St3 have deleteFlag on. My requirement is the foreign collection of Subject1 only has St1 ans St2. But when I query using SubjectDao, the collection always has 3. 
Please help me to handle this.